# ASP.NET MVC3 simple commenting system --- displaying the comments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, null, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Trying to add commenting system to my pages. I would like to be able to scaffold a list view for the for the comments on each page.

I thought i could just use the scaffold code and place it into a partialview by changing the return value to `PartialView(db.Comments.ToList());` and the `ViewResult` to a `ActionResult`.

It breaks at the `@for (item in model) {....}` with a null reference `exception error`.

So...any idea on how I do this?
EX: any commenting system anywhere.

```
    @model IEnumerable<_2nditeration.Models.Comment>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Messages";
}

<h2>Messages</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            uname
        </th>
        <th>
            email
        </th>
        <th>
            subject
        </th>
        <th>
            referrer
        </th>
        <th>
            Created
        </th>
        <th>
            comment
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@*BREAKS HERE!!!!!!with a null reference exception on the Model object*@
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.uname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.subject)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.referrer)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Created)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comment)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The Controller action

```
public class CommentsController : Controller
{
    private DbEntity db = new DbEntity();

    //
    // GET: /Comments/Read
    public ActionResult ReadComments()
    {
        return PartialView(db.Comments.ToList());
    }
```

And the model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace _2nditeration.Models
{
    public class Comment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Display ( Name = "Name")]
        public string uname { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Subject")]
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string referrer { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Created { set; get; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Comment")]
        public string comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where it breaks with the null exception?

Comment: Have you debugged through controller and checked if the db.Comments you are passing is null?

Comment: Yes the same db comment is sent to the same View, in a different action on the same controller, but not as a partial view and it renders the scaffolded table and fields fine.

Comment: You are probably passing a model to the parent view as well, try using  RenderPartial function in your parent view.

Comment: @WesleyVrancken --- thank you this was the problem. Thanks for your help.